# How to cache extension in wixtoolset using corporate artifactory instead of nuget.org

Tags: nuget, wix, artifactory

I am using wixtoolset in my work and try to cache the `WixToolset.Bal.wixext` extension as in https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixexe/#extension.

So I try to execute

```
wix extension add -g WixToolset.Bal.wixext
```

And I get

```
WixToolset.Bal.wixext : warning WIX6100: Failed to retrieve information about 'WixToolset.Bal.wixext' from remote source 'https://<artifactoryurl>/artifactory/api/nuget/<reponame>/FindPackagesById()?id='WixToolset.Bal.wixext'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
```

`nuget.org` as a source of packages is disabled in my organization but the package is available in my repo.

How to do it properly? Can I somehow supply credentials?

This seems to be ordinary nuget package which can be installed via `nuget install WixToolset.Bal.wixext` - this works without any issues with my repo.

I tried to curl the url from error and I got 401 UNAUTHORIZED. So I added the auth header `-H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: ${apikey}"` and I got results. Seems like the `wix` command ignores my nuget config file and just tries to request information over the rest api without any credentials.

As workaround I disabled artifactory source, enabled nuget.org and the command works. This however violates some policies.

Comment: did you check that you got force authentication enabled on the repository configuration? Perhaps your client is not being challenged for it.

Comment: Per my artifactory admin, yes, the force authentication is enabled on nuget repo